# error de version de git-core desde gocd

Tags: git, centos, go, gitlab

estoy trabajando en una intranet (sin conexión a Internet) en la cual tengo un servidor con sist operativo Centos7 con gocd-server instalado en el puerto 8153. Por otro lado, en la misma red, hay un servidor de GITLAB con sist operativo Centos7, con la versión de git-CORE 2.18.2.

Al intentar crear un pipeline en gocd. y establecer el material-type: GIT, me aparece el error : Please install Git-core 1.6 or above. com.thoughtworks.go.domain.materials.git.GitVersion@75ced054

Segun he estado viendo en la documentación, existe al parecer un patch, para actualizar la version (git-version-check-fix.patch) pero al intentar ejecutarlo con git apply git-version-check-fix.patch, me aparecen errores de dependencias de archivos que no existen en el servidor git.

Alguien sabe como se resuelve este problema? o alguna pista para poder lograr actualizar la version de GIT?

Comment: Creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es colocar dichos errores en la pregunta (**como texto, no con un screenshot**)

Comment: El parche que estas tratando de aplicar con `git apply`, lo estas aplicando sobre la revisión adecuada?

Comment: hola..  el error que me aparece al intentar aplicar el patch, es: Error: include/prereq-build.mk: No existe el fichero o el directorio.

Comment: la version de git que tengo instalada en el server es la 2.18.2 No se si el patch tendra sera especifico para esa version, o sera generico.

Comment: La pregunta no es sobre la version de git, sino la versión del proyecto sobre la que tienes que aplicar el parche. Si la revisión del proyecto no es la adecuada para el parche, git no lo va a poder aplicar porque podría haber diferencias en las lineas de los archivos que indica el parche para aplicarlo. A diferencia de un cherry-pick o un rebase donde git tiene todo el contexto para saber como aplicar un cambio, un parche solo indica algunas lineas antes y después de cada sección que se debe cambiar. Si las lineas no se corresponden, el `apply` falla.